# getting current file length / FileInfo.Length caching and stale information

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am keeping track of a folder of files and their file lengths, at least one of these files is still getting written to.

I have to keep a continuously updated record of each file length which I use for other purposes.

The `Update` method is called every 15 seconds and updates the file's properties if the file length differs from the length determined in the previous update.

The update method looks something like this:

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(archiveFolder);
var archiveFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles()
                                .OrderByDescending(f=>f.CreationTimeUtc); 
foreach (FileInfo fi in archiveFiles)
{
    //check if file existed in previous update already
    var origFileProps = cachedFiles.GetFileByName(fi.FullName);
    if (origFileProps != null && fi.Length == origFileProps.EndOffset)
    {
        //file length is unchanged
    }
    else
    {
        //Update the properties of this file
        //set EndOffset of the file to current file length
    }
}
```

I am aware of the fact that [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx) is pre-populating many of the `FileInfo` properties including `Length` - and this is ok as long as no caching is done *between* updates (cached information should not be older than 15 seconds).

I was under the assumption that each `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` call generates a **new** set of `FileInfos` which all are populated with fresh information right then using the `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` Win32 API. But this does not seem to be the case.

Very rarely, but eventually for sure I run into situations where the file length for a file that is getting written to is not updated for 5, 10 or even 20 minutes at a time (testing is done on Windows 2008 Server x64 if that matters).

A current workaround is to call `fi.Refresh()` to force an update on each file info. This internally seems to delegate to a `GetFileAttributesEx` Win32 API call to update the file information.

While the cost of forcing a refresh manually is tolerable I would rather understand *why* I am getting stale information in the first place. When is the `FileInfo` information generated and how does it relate to the call of  `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` ? Is there a file I/O caching layer underneath that I don't fully grasp?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Raymond Chen has now written a very detailed blog post about exactly this issue:

[**Why is the file size reported incorrectly for files that are still being written to?**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813)

> In NTFS, **file system metadata is a property not of the directory entry
> but rather of the file, with some of the metadata replicated into the
> directory entry as a tweak to improve directory enumeration
> performance**. Functions like Find­First­File report the directory
> entry, and by putting the metadata that FAT users were accustomed to
> getting "for free", they could avoid being slower than FAT for
> directory listings. **The directory-enumeration functions report the
> last-updated metadata, which may not correspond to the actual metadata
> if the directory entry is stale.**

Essentially it comes down to performance: The directory information gathered from `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` and the `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` Win32 API underneath is cached for performance reasons to guarantee better performance in NTFS than in the old FAT for acquiring directory information. Accurate file size information can only be acquired by calling `Get­File­Size()` on a file directly (in .NET call `Refresh()` on the `FileInfo` or acquire a `FileInfo` from the file name directly) - or opening and closing the file stream which causes the updated file information to be propagated to the directory metadata cache. The later case explains why the file size is immediately updated when the writing process closes the file.

This also explains that the problem seemingly did not show up in Windows 2003 Server - back then the file info was replicated more often / whenever the cache was flushed - this is not the case anymore for Windows 2008 Server:

> As for how often, the answer is a little more complicated. Starting in
> Windows Vista (and its corresponding Windows Server version which I
> don't know but I'm sure you can look up, and by "you" I mean "Yuhong
> Bao"), the NTFS file system performs this courtesy replication when
> the last handle to a file object is closed. **Earlier versions of NTFS
> replicated the data while the file was open whenever the cache was
> flushed, which meant that it happened every so often according to an
> unpredictable schedule. The result of this change is that the
> directory entry now gets updated less frequently, and therefore the
> last-updated file size is more out-of-date than it already was.**

Reading the full article is very informative and recommended!

Answer (score 6):

I thik that you should use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and subscribe Changed event. It is triggered when specified file system item is changed.

Comment: +1 for a sensible suggestion - at this point I do have a workaround and in the long run most likely will refactor to using a FileSystemWatcher - but this doesn't answer to *why* I am getting stale information which is what this question is all about

Comment: IMO there must by some OS cashing layer. Even if you invoke stream.Flush() it won't force saving on HD. Have you tried to disable disk write caching? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259716

Comment: In lack of any other explanation I will accept this answer as a workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Wojteq that using the FileSystemWatcher class would be a better solution. It exposes events for when different attributes of a file or directory change (such as the Change event that he referenced) and it is a better solution than the polling solution that is currently in place. To answer your question about why the Refresh takes variable amounts of time to reflect a change in a file's size the answer is that is has to do with the underlying Virtual Memory Manager of the Windows operating system. When File I/O is performed it actually does updates against memory-mapped files; this is a buffered copy of the file that is managed by the operating system. So, Windows controls when the buffered data is written to disk. There is no way to predict when a particular piece of buffered data will be physically written to disk. This means that updating a file stream will place those updates in the buffer. If you were to Flush() the stream the buffered updates should be written to disk immediately, if you close the stream then it will be written from buffer to disk just after the stream is closed, and if the stream is held open it is up to Windows when it decides to write the buffered data to disk.

Comment: buffering would explain update delays in the order of seconds but not minutes, the writing code is in C and uses `fwrite` which by default uses a buffer size of not more than a few kilo bytes AFAIK.

Comment: +1 Definitely it does have something to do with the file still being written to, I noticed I get a correct update right away once the writing process stops. The stale information problem very rarely happens though, that still begs the question *why* this happens in the first place