# DirectoryInfo doesn't create directory

Tags: c#, .net

This has to be something silly but I just don't see it. So I have this code:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo("somedir");
if (dir.Exists) {
   dir.Delete(true);
}
dir.Create();
```

If the directory **DOESN'T EXIST** the directory is created just fine. If the directory **EXISTS** then no directory is created. Why?

Comment: Whoever downgraded and requested to close this issue please explain.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can't recreate the issue. I did `var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test\DirTest");` and it worked both with and without `DirTest` existing.

Comment: Maybe it's OS or framework version specific..

Comment: @Denis perhaps you should get more accustom with wrapping your `if()` conditions around `{ }`

Comment: I agree with @ScottChamberlain the problem is not reproducible. More info is needed. What framework and what OS and exactly what is the dir path involved.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem, I have windows 8.1 and I use .NET 4.5

Comment: @YacoubMassad I am on 8.1 and 4.5 and it works fine.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 x64 Enterprise and using .NET framework 4

Comment: Very strange, I tried it again now and I cannot reproduce. I am sure that I reproduced it multiple times before.

Comment: could it be possible that I had that directory open in explorer somewhere and the delete happened but for some reason the create didn't happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo("somedir");
if (dir.Exists)
{
   dir.Delete(true);
   dir.Refresh();
}

dir.Create();
```

You need to [refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) after the delete to update the state info.

Comment: knew it had to be something silly. Awesome! That works!

Comment: Looking through the refrence source I can't find any reason calling [`Refresh()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/filesysteminfo.cs.html#1c7b7d54ada1ef87) would fix this issue. [`dir.Create()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs.html#368db83772a7dab0) calls the static method `Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(FullPath, OriginalPath, null, true);`, no state information (specifically the field `_dataInitialised` ) is passed in.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828132/getting-current-file-length-fileinfo-length-caching-and-stale-information) seems to have the detail on why it works.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I did the same research and found no indication why should `Refresh` work, I've have not seen any watcher over `_dataInitialised` or seen any method execute to handle the change of the Directory state, I'm now reading on Win32 API about what is the "last handle" is meant, when they wrote "The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed.` Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @OrelEraki See "[Deleted but not yet forgotten](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040607-00/?p=38993)" from the MSDN blog, it may help explain that term a bit. I happened to run across that link yesterday when I was making a answer about `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Thank you mate.. :)

Comment: Updated link to the "Old New thing" on [Deleted but not yet forgotten](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040607-00/?p=38993)