# Currently used data file growth is not reflected by FileInfo.Length

Tags: c#, windows, filesize, ntfs, fileinfo

I need to get the size of a database file ideally without opening it. In fact I need to launch an event when the file changes. 
It is a DataFlex DAT file, quite obsolete database application.
The file is being open and used by the database application and FileInfo reports the size incorrectly.

Probably the reason is described here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813

I am using this C# construct:

```
private FileInfo _dbFileInfo = new FileInfo("...");
...

_dbFileInfo.Refresh();
var len = _dbFileInfo.Length;
```

But the `_dbFileInfo.Length` does not change when the file grows.
Is there any workaround for this problem without actually examining the file content?

Comment: Found one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828132/getting-current-file-length-fileinfo-length-caching-and-stale-information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the lines

```
_dbFileInfo.Refresh();
var len = _dbFileInfo.Length;
```

to

```
long len;
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(_dbFileInfo.FullName, 
                                 FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
     len = fs.Length;
     fs.Close();
}
```

And now it works. Though not sure if it is the best approach.